How do I restart a service in a docker stack when doing a stack deploy?
I'm using docker swarm and docker compose to stand up ~6 services. One of those services is from a docker image that doesn't change often, but what does change is the config file on the host machine that I'm mounting as a volume into the container.
Since the image doesn't change, the service isn't restarted when I do a new docker stack deploy command, and the changes to the config file aren't picked up (since the config file is only read at start-up).
What I currently do is docker stack rm my-stack to kill everything, and then docker stack deploy my-stack. It's fine, I guess, but I wonder if there's a better way to force service restarts rather than killing everything and have 20s of downtime while it starts back up.
Thanks.

If its a config file, then use docker configs not a host mount. each time you update the config reference (configs are immutable) the service will be restarted.
